# Reading the source code of a page in Java

Tags: java, html, http, get, request

So I was trying to get the source code of a page in Java. What I did was to make a GET request using HttpURLConnection. I used BufferedReader to read the source code. However, I was only able to read a part of it, after that, the BufferedReader object only returned null. I've also used Jsoup and that worked well. So I can't really figure out why my first approach didn't work. Here is how my code looked like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        while (reader.ready())
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
```

Comment: I think perhaps you should go back to a tutorial on using readers, like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html). You should *not* have a `while (true)` there. This means it will work forever. And your intepretation of `reader.ready()` is wrong - it's not something you base a `while` on, and it's not necessary to wait until the reader will not block.

Comment: Well, the code that you edited, did you try running it and seeing if it works?

Comment: @RealSkeptic ops, really embarassing. Thank you!

Comment: It appears you found a solution and edited the code in your question to use that solution.  As a result, there is no longer a valid question here.  Is that correct?

Comment: @VGR Yes, but I wasn't sure if I should delete the question.

Comment: It is better to provide an answer to your own question (and Stack sites even encourage people to do so).  By leaving the original text of your question and providing the solution you found, the information can help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the wrong way of checking if there is something to read from the stream (as RealSkeptic said)

This is the correct way:

```
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(line);
```